# loading dropdown with value

Tags: c#, html, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a dropdown that gets data on the fly i want to show existing selection when page loads and let the user pick one from list if they want.

there is site which has all the data related to a site and i want my dropdown to get existing value from site.market lets say newyork. The dropdown list is created dynamically.
 This is the aspx

```
<tr>

  <td class="large"><asp:DropDownList ID="dropmarket" runat="server"  ></asp:DropDownList></td>

</tr>
```

in aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            market();
            CellSiteUtility utility = new CellSiteUtility();
            var siteID = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());

            var site = utility.GetCellSiteByID(siteID);

            if (site != null)
            {

                txtsitename.Text = site.SiteName;
                txtaddress.Text = site.SiteAddress;
                txtzip.Text = site.SiteCityStateZip;
                dropmanager.SelectedValue = site.Manager;
                dropmarket.SelectedValue = site.Market;

            }
        }

    private void market()
    {
        CellSiteUtility utility = new CellSiteUtility();
        var siteID = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
        var market = utility.getMarketsByCellsiteID(siteID);

        foreach (t_Market m in market)
        {
            dropmarket.Items.Add(new ListItem(m.MarketName.ToString(),
                m.MarketId.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

how can I load `site.market` into `dropmarket` when page loads?
thanks in advance.

Comment: This question should be voted down.

Comment: This is a very confusing question. Can you clean up to only show the pertitant code, and explain a bit better?

Comment: In the market() method, you populate dropmarket with ListItems and set their Value property to MarketID. Then when you set the SelectedValue of dropmarket, you set it to site.Market. Shouldn't you be setting it to site.Market.MarketID as well?

Comment: site .market is from a stored proc result that gives me current market name from db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may select a list item on Page_Load:

```
ListItem selectedListItem = dropmarket.Items.FindByValue(site.Market);
if (selectedListItem != null)
{
    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
};
```

or

```
dropmarket.SelectedIndex = 0;
if (dropmarket.Items.Contains(site.Market))
   dropmarket.SelectedIndex = dropmarket.Items.IndexOf(entry);
```

---

### Edit:

This example assumes that site.Market is the value from the dropdown list. As in:

```
<option value="somevalue">SomeText</option>
```

If site.Market is the text from the dropdown, use:

```
ListItem selectedListItem = dropmarket.Items.FindByText(site.Market);
```

Hope this helps!

Vivek

Comment: Thank you vivek the following worked ListItem selectedListItem = dropmarket.Items.FindByText(site.Market);
if (selectedListItem != null)
{
    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
};

Comment: Good that it helped! I have edited the answer to add your scenario too :)